# Prolog: slice big list in smaller seperate lists

Tags: prolog

I'm searching for an opportunity to slice a list into smaller lists, like that:

```
[1,2,3,4] -> [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
[1,2] -> [[1,2]]
```

and so on..

First, I searched for an solution with build-in predicates. But I couldn't figure it out to do it with them.. Is this right?!
So I wrote an own predicate:

```
slice([],[]).
slice([H1,H2|T], Output) :-
    append([H2],T,New),
    slice(New, [[H1,H2]|Output]).
```

But in the last iteration step, when New only consists of one element, the unification with [H1,H2|T] fails..

Answer (score 2):

Define `slice/2` based on [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`mapadj/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31975346/4609915) in tandem with [Prolog lambdas](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord)! Simply write:

```
slice(Xs,Yss) :-
   mapadj(\X0^X1^[X0,X1]^true, Xs, Yss).
```

Sample queries:

```
?- slice([1,2],Yss).
Yss = [[1,2]].

?- slice([1,2,3,4],Yss).
Yss = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]].
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on that answer from @SergeyDymchenko, much depends on how you want to deal with the special case of a list of a single element, `[1]`.

Do you discard it, such that

```
[1] --> []
```

If so, Sergey's answer is correct.

Or, do you 'slice' it into a sublist of a single element, such that

```
[1] --> [ [1] ]
```

If so, you'll need to modify the 2nd term of Sergey's answer:

```
slice( []      , []            ) .
slice( [H]     , [ [H] ]       ) .
slice( [H1,H2|T] , [[H1,H2]|R] ) :-
  slice( [H2|T] , R )
  .
```

The third alernative would be to simply fail, treating a list of a single element as invalid input to the predicate: A list of a single element can't be decomposed into list of 2-element sublists, each consisting of adjacent pairs.

Only you can determine semantics of truth for this problem.

Comment: Your second alternative doesn't conform to tests examples from the question.

Comment: @SergeyDymchenko - since the OP didn't give an example of a single element list, though he alluded to it being the problem, I rather suspect it's a special case her analysis did not consider. In either event, the question does not specified the desired treatment of a single element list: whether that single element should cause failure, be excluded from the result set or be included in the result set as a short sublist.

Comment: there is no posibility to fail on single element, because you will invariably hit the single-element list if you start with any longer list.

Answer (score 0):

```
slice([], []).
slice([_], []) :- !.
slice([H1, H2 | T], [[H1, H2] | SliceT]) :-
    slice([H2 | T], SliceT).
```